# Facebook Page - Photos Upload by others

Tags: facebook, photos, facebook-pages

I have activated the option where fans can upload photos on my facebook page. When they upload the photos it hasnt created a album called Photos by others.

my page: http://facebook.com/bakasurain

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be working now.
[image]

Comment: yeah :) looks like they had some problem :) thanks